# How does Strategy Pattern alter runtime behaviour of an application and Template doesn't?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Why do we say that Strategy pattern alters **runtime** behaviour but Template pattern alters**static behavior**, when we can specify both strategy & template to be chosen at runtime?

Comment: I can't understand your meaning but I know that the Template pattern is used to run some methods based on a template like first run initialize() then run run() after that finish() then we can call them in a method to do all of them but Strategy pattern is used to do some methods with different purposes but with same arguments.If it help you I wonder if you hit the up arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strategy is implemented via composition (client has-a strategy). Template Method is implemented via inheritance (client is-a template). Composition is a runtime relationship. Inheritance is a compile-time (static) relationship.

A client can change strategies at runtime. Changing templates requires implementing a new client.

Comment: Thanks jaco0646. So the difference lies at a conceptual level alone, right? It has nothing to do with performance or execution of code.

Comment: Well, composition vs inheritance is a difference in implementation. The code is different, but it has nothing to do with performance.

Comment: If I use a template pattern, the abstract (generalized) class of template would still be referred by a client class and the client would specify which template to call. If we allow this choice to be made by the user at runtime, how will template be different from Strategy pattern?

Comment: How does the client refer to the abstract, generalized class? Inheritance or composition? If the client refers to the abstraction by inheritance (i.e. `MyClient extends AbstractClass`) then how can the client choose a different abstraction at runtime? Choosing a reference at runtime presumes composition; but there is no composition relationship in the Template Method pattern. Template Method has only two participants: parent class and child class. The child is the client.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean C++ template. I would not get it for the Template Design pattern.

In C++, templates are evaluated at compile time. So for example when you do:

```
std::vector<std::string> a;
std::vector<int> b;
```

There actually 2 completely independant vector class, each one optimzed for the given type.

So if your strategy depend only of the type of data for example you can just define a struct:

template< class T >
struct myStrategy;

Then you could define yout strategy for a given type (let say int):

```
template <>
struct myStrategy<int> {
 public:
  void strategy()(const int&i) const {
    // Strategy for int
  }
};
```

And then to apply the strategy:

myStrategy(3);

With template meta programming you can add many check on the types for various implementation like if they are a container, or whatever else. It also easy for anybody to extend the supported types even as client to your library and the matching is done at compile time so no performance penalty.

You could argue then that there can be only 1 definition per type but it isn't true. If we take the classical of std::hash & std::equal_to, you can provide a more advanced template with default value. So when using your unordered_map:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

You see you can use the standard implementation for your strategy of hashing/comparison (by default) or you can provide a custom one...

But this isn't really neither Strategy or Template design pattern. It is more using C++ template functionallity and using types & functional programming (optionnaly) to solve the design problem.

Comment: The question is tagged as _Java_. Why would it be asking about C++ Templates?

Comment: Agree but then I really don't get this "runtime" behavior. Java has no way to make choice at compile time like templates.